# STL correct use of find_if() to print out odd numbers

Tags: c++, stl

How can I possibly make use of the *find_if* algorithm from STL to find and print out odd numbers from a *vector*?

Let me just give you an example of what I'm on about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


bool isOdd(int x)
{
    return x%2 == 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int tab[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    vector<int> myVec(tab, tab + sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]));
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    // Printing out all numbers

    cout << "Vector contains the following numbers: " << endl;

    for(it = myVec.begin(), it != myVec.end(), ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }

    // An unsuccessful attempt to print out odd numbers while using find_if and while loop

    vector<int>::iterator bound = find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), isOdd);

    while(bound != myVec.end())
    {
       cout << *bound << ' ';
    }

 }
```

What is wrong with while loop? I guess it's the core problem of my code.

I'm assigning whatever the *find_if* function will return to the iterator, and then I simply can't figure out how to cherry-pick odd values from the *vector* ;(

Comment: `find_if` finds just the first one, so you'd need to do something like calling it in a loop. I'd use `copy_if` together with `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: @T.C. I would love to see how it can work with while loop, since I have stumbled upon similar example which used while loop, unfortunately I can't simply recall how it was done.

Comment: Your `isOdd` is really `isEven`...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not advancing the iterator in your loop:

```
while(bound != myVec.end())
{
    cout << *bound << ' '; 
    bound = find_if(bound+1, myVec.end(), isOdd);
}
```

In C++11 you can use [`std::next(bound)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead of `bound+1`.

Also, your `isOdd` returns `true` when the number is even. It should be

```
bool isOdd(int x) 
{ 
   return x%2 != 0; 
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/IlPzi5)

Comment: +1, The `for` loop won't go far without semicolons, too.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding that for this use I'd just use `std::copy_if`:

```
std::copy_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), isOdd);
```

Similarly, the first `for` loop in your code (and those should be semicolons, not commas) can be replaced with `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24c4c07fc962e8fa).